# JTable's setValueAt() method is not updating cell data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a JTable using Abstract Table Model. This table has a two dimensional array of Integer object data and one 1 dimensional column header.Everything works fine except when I edit & change the cell data during program's runtime, it reverts back to the default value (created with getValueAt()). I have implemented Abstract Table Models setValueAt() method but it does not work.

Can anyone please tell me whats is wrong in my code?

```
    import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

    public class TableModel1 extends AbstractTableModel {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    String [] colNames=new String[30];  
    Object[][] data= new Integer[4][30];            


    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return colNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 4;  
    }


    public String getColumnName(int col){

        if (col==0){
            colNames[0]="Boarders";
            }

        else if(col>0){
            for(int i=1;i<colNames.length;i++){
                 colNames[i]=new String(""+i);
            }
        }
    return colNames[col];
    }


    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {


        for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<data[i].length;j++){
                data[i][j]=new Integer(1);
                 }
                     }
        return data[row][col];
    }  


    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {            
          return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
        }


    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
        return true;
    }

    public void  setValueAt (Object aValue, int row, int col){

            data[row][col]=(Integer)aValue;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);

    }

 }//end class
```

Comment: Please Note:  In my case I was filling again  the table on  windowActivated event. So it was overwriting my data with load time data. Please use the proper event now i used "formWindowOpened" event.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that happens because when `getValueAt()` method invokes, you always refresh data in your array with next lines:

```
for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<data[i].length;j++){
            data[i][j]=new Integer(1);
        }
}
```

So, remove this lines from `getValueAt()` method, and initialize your array in constructor of your model only once not every time as now.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the getValueAt . those methods are constantly called. its not a one time thing. initiate the values outside of the table model